# Как правильно назвать данное явление (фактические и формальные параметры)?

Tags: терминология

фактический параметр — аргумент, используемый как значение (число, символ и т. д.);
формальный параметр — аргумент, используемый как ячейка памяти (название переменной, указатель на переменную), выступающее в качестве идентификатора этого значения, принимаемого функцией.

Чаще называют как по ссылке или по значению, это вырезка из вики. Преподаватель на лекции сказал другую вещь, что формальные параметры это параметры которые используются при объявлении функции, а вот при вызове функции то это называется фактическими параметрами.

Кому верить? Что-то мне кажется преподаватель бред гонит...

Comment: http://crasseux.com/books/ctutorial/Actual-parameters-and-formal-parameters.html

Comment: Все правильно говорит препод. Преподу респект.

Comment: Хм, я думал что те что используются в объявлении называются параметрами, те что при вызове -- аргументами.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Большинство компиляторов игнорируют имена аргументов внутри определения функции, им интересен только тип данных, поэтому это все высосано из пальца.

Другими словами:

```
int myfunction(int a); //Объявление. Формальный параметр. 
                       //Аргумент указывает компилятору что нужно выделить 4 байта памяти в стэке для хранения параметра типа int при вызове функции.

int myfunction(int b) //Определение. Формальный параметр.
{
   return 0;
}

int main()
{
    int c=0;
    myfunction(c); //Вызов. Фактический параметр. 
                   //Аргумент действительно используется как значение(0).
    return 0;
}
//'a' и 'b' могут не совпадать. Кроме того 'a' может воообще не быть. Это сделано для удобства использования. Главное чтобы int совпало во всех случаях, до выполнения программы.
```

P.S. Индусский код получился. 3 раза подряд возвращает ноль

Comment: С вашего позволения, использую этот пример в соотв. статье на Википедии. Единственно, слегка изменю комментарии.

Comment: Пожалуйста, я буду только рад.

Comment: Странная фраза.

     "Большинство компиляторов игнорируют имена аргументов внутри определения функции, им интересен только тип данных"

Имена аргументов используются в теле функции для указания на параметры. Без них обходятся при point-free описаниях функций в функциональном программировании и стековых языках (forth, postscript и т.д.)

Comment: > Большинство компиляторов игнорируют имена аргументов внутри определения функции

Наверное, имелось в виду не определение, а объявление

Comment: Я имею в виду что в объявлении и определении могут не совпадать имена переменных, в самом теле естественно должны совпадать с тем что написано в первой строчке определения, чтобы можно было обеспечить доступ к ним.

Answer (score 4):

Гростно, разве это важно? Давай думать логически, формальные - это что-то неопределенное, логически - это те, которые используются при обьевлении, фактические - это те, которые используются ПО ФАКТУ, т.е при непосредственном вызове.

Comment: Такое размышление напоминает старый анекдот:  
Формально у нас есть 2 миллиона :)

Answer (score 2):

Да, всё правильно. Ещё Visual Studio при определении функции, которая не использует какой-то из своих аргументов, выдаёт предупреждение "неиспользуемый формальный параметр".

А вообще я и не думал, что эти `формальности` так важны :). Какая разница как называть, если на результат - программу, это никак не повлияет?

Comment: Да, но некоторым буквоедам это важно

Comment: "А вообще я и не думал, что эти формальности так важны :)"

Можно сказать "поверни направо" и показать налево. Остаётся только понять, куда же нужно поворачивать.

Comment: Это нужно для общения, чтобы каждой вещи соответствовал свой термин, чтобы не путаться. Кроме того, программирование как таковое было создано сначала на бумаге математиками, а там формализм - самое главное. Формализм - вообще-то вещь довольно хорошая, когда используется по назначению.

Comment: >Это нужно для общения, чтобы каждой вещи соответствовал свой термин, чтобы не путаться.

 Он на практике почти никогда не употребляется. А в редких случаях, когда он нужен, можно сказать другими словами, пусть и более длинно.

Comment: @GLmonster, зачем говорит длинно, когда есть способ сказать короче и точнее? Во владении терминологией - залог настоящего профессионализма ИМХО.

Comment: @GLmonster Краморовское "дерево" из "Джентльменов удачи"?

     Вот оно -- дерево!

Comment: Если тупо сидеть за учебниками и зубрить терминологию, программированию не научишься. А тем, кто научился программированию на практике, но не выучил термины, так будет понятнее.

 Ладно, не вижу смысла спорить, всё равно каждый останется при своём мнении.